# how to convert decimal time to datetime so I can run dateadd calculation on it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a MSSQL table where the raw data is formatted as this:

```
date1                time1

2008-01-20 00:00:00   654
2008-01-20 00:00:00   659
2008-01-20 00:00:00   1759
```

and I need to join both of them together so I can query for example all date_time that happened in the last 15 hours. what I did was

in the select statement:

```
combined = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Date1, 103) +' ' + (left((replace((CONVERT(dec(7, 2), time1) / 100 ),'.',':')),4) + ':00') ,
```

This helped me with getting results for

```
date1                time1  combined1

2008-01-20 00:00:00   654  20/01/2008 6:54:00
2008-01-20 00:00:00   659  20/01/2008 6:59:00
2008-01-20 00:00:00   1759 20/01/2008 17:5:00
```

I can`t change the table data & I can`t get the right syntax to convert it fully (including taking in consideration the 24h hour format - 1759 for example)

And in the end I need to be able to do a where statement on the combined1 column to see only the rows that happened in the last 15 hours

```
DATEADD(hour, - 15, GETDATE())
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
select date1,time1, DATEADD(MINUTE, time1%100, DATEADD(HOUR, time1/100, convert(varchar(10),date1,101))) as Combined 
from Table
Where DATEADD(MINUTE, time1%100, DATEADD(HOUR, time1/100, convert(varchar(10),date1,101)))>(DATEADD(hour,-15,GETDATE()))
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, although the feel is like it take some more time to do the calculation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '2008-01-20 00:00:00'
,       @Time INT = 654

SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, @Time%100, DATEADD(HOUR, @Time/100, @date))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT CAST('2008-01-20 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS date1,   654 AS Time1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('2008-01-20 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS date1,   659 AS Time1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST('2008-01-20 00:00:00' AS DATETIME) AS date1,  1759 AS Time1
)

SELECT 
    DATEADD(ms, DATEDIFF(ms, '00:00:00', CAST(FORMAT(Time1, '##:##') AS TIME)),  date1) AS [CombinedDateTime]
FROM cte;

--Results to: 

CombinedDateTime
2008-01-20 06:54:00.000
2008-01-20 06:59:00.000
2008-01-20 17:59:00.000
```